# C# MongoDB -> MongoDatabase.Drop() doesn't delete the db itself

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to completely remove a database (delete all collections and the db itself).

When I do it from Robomongo (right click on the db -> drop database) it works as expected, but when using the driver from c# it just removes all collections of the db.

The method I am calling is: `MongoDatabase.Drop()`. I am using MongoDB.Driver in .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 10):

Just for sake of completeness, the driver v2.3 has:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
client.DropDatabase(dbName);
```